# Reset the origin refs after changing git origin

Tags: git, branch

Our project has just moved to a new repository, so I updated the origin:

```
$ git remote set-url origin git://new.url.here
$ git fetch origin
```

The problem is, our new repository doesn't have a lot of the old branches, but these branches are still showing up:

```
$ git branch -r
  origin/foo
  origin/bar
  origin/fubar
  ... a long list of branches that aren't really there ...
```

How can I clear out those refs so that I only see branches that really exist on the remote?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer in `man git-fetch`.

Use the `-p` or `--prune` option: *"After fetching, remove any remote-tracking branches which no longer exist on the remote."*

```
$ git fetch -p origin
 x [deleted]         (none)     -> origin/foo
 x [deleted]         (none)     -> origin/bar
 x [deleted]         (none)     -> origin/fubar
...
```